# How can I reshape a Japanese maple with dead branches in the centre

Tags: pruning, japanese-maple

[image]

I have a minuature Japanese Maple 'Deshojo' bought 2 years ago and it has done well since. I live in Northern France, it is in full sun in the afternoon but there are only a few weeks it is really hot here.

The top of the central branch has died. If I trim it out the dead section, it will leave a 'hole' in the centre and the other branches are quite spread out. Could I perhaps pull them in to the centre a little by tying a strap around them? Also, I believe I should wait until spring to trim it, is that correct?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information instead of making a new post. Thanks and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Any pruning required should be done while the tree is dormant, before the sap rises in spring, or from late August onwards, so clip out the dead parts now. I understand what you mean when you say taking the dead parts out will leave a gap in the centre, but a dead branch will produce no growth anyway. I wouldn't recommend tying  it up to try to cover up the empty centre - over time, new growth from surrounding branches will fill in the gap, but if you want it to look a bit more even than it does, lightly trim back and shape side/surrounding branches now to reduce the length, particularly of the longer branches.